# Elasticity of solid

Tags: homework-and-exercises, elasticity, stress-strain

A rod $1m$ long is $10cm^2$ in area for a portion of its length and $5cm^2$ in area for the remaining. The strain energy of this stepped bar is $40$% of that a bar $10cm^2$ in area and $1m$ long under the same maximum stress. What is the length of the portion $10cm^2$ in area.

**My attempt:**

$$strain-energy = \frac{1}{2}(stress)^2 × \frac{volume}{Y}$$

where $Y$ is Young's modulus.

Since the material of both the rods is the same so $Y$ is same and stress is also same so $40$% of the volume of the uniform rod = volume of the stepped rod. But this expression is not yielding the result. I am confused as what do the line " under same maximum stress" mean in the question as for same force stress cannot be same. Where I am wrong.

Comment: Please use mathjax to format mathematical expressions. To learn more about mathjax, please read [MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tension is same same all along the length of the composite bar, as it is in the uniform bar. So the stress will be higher where the cross-section is lower.

The question is saying that the stress in the narrow section of the composite bar is the same as in the uniform bar with which it is being compared.

Comment: Will you tell me how you figured out that stress in the narrower part is same as that of stress of uniform rod.

Comment: I did not figure it out - the question states that this is the case when it says "under the same maximum stress". The stress in the uniform bar (which is the same all the way along) is equal to the stress in the narrow part of the composite bar, because that section is where the maximum stress is in the composite bar.

Comment: The main problem was that statement only, I got it